# Why does VirtualBox crash when I finish the install of BackTrack?

Tags: virtualbox, backtrack, crash

I have a windows 7 64-bit machine in which I have installed VirtualBox and decided to install BackTrack. The installation finished fine, but when it asked me to "please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press ENTER" VirtualBox crashes.

I have tried going  through the installation process twice but it has crashed both times.

Additional Info just in case:
Host operating system: windows 7 64-bit 6GB of RAM, I5

[image]

[image]

**SOLVED**: As I said in the comment below I found out that the crash does not affects the install...just restart virtualbox and start backtrack. But I still don't know what is causing this.

Comment: If anyone comes to this question scare because you virtualbox crashed too, then don't fear. I found out that the crash does not affects the install...just restart virtualbox and start backtrack.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I can tell it crashed at `reboot`, so it would be a bug of VirtualBox, that it doesn't handle these requests correctly on Win 64, there's nothing you can do.

[Fire a bug reprt here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker)

Answer (score 1):

Instead using BackTrack Linux, that is based on Ubuntu 11.04 (dates back to the 2011), you could be using Kali Linux that includes all the latest updates of all the tools, fixes several updates problems, and is in general a more usable Distribution than BackTrack. This is also recommended by the same guys that developed BackTrack:

> From the creators of BackTrack comes Kali Linux, the most advanced and versatile penetration testing distribution ever created. BackTrack has grown far beyond its humble roots as a live CD and has now become a full-fledged operating system.
>
> “So, what’s the difference between BackTrack and Kali?” you might be asking. Unfortunately for us, that’s not a simple question to answer. It’s a mix between “everything” and “not much”, depending on how you used BackTrack.
>
> Our new streamlined repositories synchronize with the Debian repositories 4 times a day, constantly providing you with the latest package updates and security fixes available.
>
> Many of the tools in our toolbox need to be “bleeding edge”. This means we have take on the task of packaging and maintaining upstream versions of many tools, so that our users are constantly kept up to date where it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this application and Virtual Box are not compatible.  BTW, not all programs can be operated in a virtual environment as much as we all would like it to be.  You might want to pose this to the BackTrack people for their analysis.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I found out that this crash does not affect anything.  I restarted virtualbox and started backtrack fine.

Answer (score 0):

try with backtrack 32 bits.. 64 bits seems crash virtualbox even your computer is 64 bits.

Comment: Or better yet, use Kali Linux. Backtrack is an abandoned project.